A strange behavior about output_shapes in tf.data.Dataset.from_generator
A data generator is defined in a VGG16 transfer learning model. The input shape of image is (224, 224, 3). Here is the generator defined:
def preprocess_image_patches_image_embedding(image_paths, user_ids, binary_flags, window_size=(224, 224), step_size=112):
    """Preprocess image patches and return a dataset of patches and their labels."""
    image_patches = []
    #patch_labels = []
    label_user_ids = []
    label_binary_flags = []
    
    for img_path, user_id, binary_flag in zip(image_paths, user_ids, binary_flags):
        random_userid = random_user_id(user_id)
        print(f'random user id picked : {random_userid}')
        for patch, _ in create_patches([img_path], window_size, step_size):
            #print(f'Patch shape before appending: {patch.shape}')
            image_patches.append(patch)
            #patch_labels.append(label)
            label_user_ids.append(user_id)
            label_binary_flags.append(binary_flag)
            #fabricate a false data when binary_flag is true/1
            #print(f'binary flag in image patch : {binary_flag}')
            if binary_flag == 1:
                image_patches.append(patch)
                label_user_ids.append(random_userid)
                label_binary_flags.append(0)                
            
            if len(image_patches) == BATCH_SIZE:      #min BATCH_SIZE is 2                
                yield (np.array(image_patches), np.array(label_user_ids)), (np.array(label_user_ids), np.array(label_binary_flags))
                
                # Clear the lists for the next batch
                image_patches = []
                label_user_ids = []
                label_binary_flags = []
            
        #handle not equal case
        if len(image_patches) > 0:
            yield (np.array(image_patches), np.array(label_user_ids)), (np.array(label_user_ids), np.array(label_binary_flags))

Here is the data generated:
patch_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: preprocess_image_patches_image_embedding(image_paths, label_user_ids, label_binary_flags, window_size, step_size),
        output_types=((tf.float32, tf.int32),(tf.int32, tf.int32)),
        output_shapes=(((None, 224, 224, 3), (None,)), ((None,), (None,)))
    )

However the above defined shapes throw error:
  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/aimodels/common/prepare_data_vgg16.py", line 258, in model_fit_image_label_array
    history = model.fit(
              ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/layers/input_spec.py", line 245, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "functional" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, None, 224, 224, 3) 
 #<<==double None here, even there is only one None in output shape

What I did was to remove None from the output_shapes:
patch_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: preprocess_image_patches_image_embedding(image_paths, label_user_ids, label_binary_flags, window_size, step_size),
    output_types=((tf.float32, tf.int32),(tf.int32, tf.int32)),
    output_shapes=(((224, 224, 3), ()), ((), ())). #<<==remove None in shape
)

However there is also error:
  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/from_generator_op.py", line 235, in generator_py_func
    raise TypeError(

TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (2, 224, 224, 3) where an element of shape (224, 224, 3) was expected.


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_2]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (2, 224, 224, 3) where an element of shape (224, 224, 3) was expected.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/home/aiworker9/code/py/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/from_generator_op.py", line 235, in generator_py_func
    raise TypeError(

TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (2, 224, 224, 3) where an element of shape (224, 224, 3) was expected.
 #<<==None was not in shape as expected

I don't understand is that a single None added to the output shape becomes 2 None in data generator's output and causes error. Here is the tensorFlow doc for data generator.
